# Exception in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a .NET Developer and I'm creating an API for logging exceptions.

Now I'm creating one for objective-c.

My question is: what data are found in the exception in objective-c?

In .NET we have stacktrace , message...etc what are the ones in objective-c?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

Please note that I know in objective-c there is try catch block. This isn't what I'm asking for. the exception has data in it such as code(error code). What else there?

Java for example have stack trace. .NET have stack trace and message.

What are the one's in objective c?

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html)

Comment: Consult the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the [`NSException` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for information about which properties and methods it supports.

Note however that catching exceptions is extremely uncommon in Objective-C, in particular, exceptions are never used for control flow, which is different from other languages/frameworks you may be used to.

Exceptions are mostly raised for *programmer errors* that should be fixed in your code instead of being caught at runtime. Other types of errors are usually represented as an `NSError`. The [Exception Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012i) documentation has some more details about this.

In the chapter [Exceptions and the Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/ExceptionsAndCocoaFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009045-SW1), it also notes that:

> The Cocoa frameworks are generally not exception-safe. The general pattern is that exceptions are reserved for programmer error only, and the program catching such an exception should quit soon afterwards.

Comment: my friend just a small hint if you may, the NSError has the following values : code, domain, user info and the localized Error Description. Correct?